# In Jinja2, how to make a string in single quotes is highlighted as blue?

Tags: vim, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm using [salt-vim](https://github.com/saltstack/salt-vim) to highlight YAML and Jinja2.

I would like to use single quotes for pillar.get or concatenate strings:

[image]

but also want to highlight the string as blue like in the second line.

How to do that?

My `~/.vimrc`:

```
set backup
let day = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
let user = substitute(system('whoami'), '\n', '', '')
if user == 'root'
    let backupdir = "/var/root/.vim/backup/".day
else
    let backupdir = $HOME."/.vim/backup/".day
endif
silent! let xyz = mkdir(backupdir, "p")
let cmd = "set backupdir=".backupdir
execute cmd
let time = strftime(".%H:%M:%S")
let cmd = "set backupext=".time
execute cmd

syntax on
set number
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors = 256
let g:solarized_visibility = "high"
let g:solarized_contrast = "high"
let g:solarized_termtrans = 1
colorscheme solarized

autocmd FileType python set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab

"autocmd FileType rst set syntax=rest

set clipboard=unnamed
execute pathogen#infect()
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"

filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" powerline

" end of powerline

set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jinja2 set filetype=sls.jinja2

nnoremap <F6> :GundoToggle<CR>

" ultisnips
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir ="~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/UltiSnips"
let g:UltiSnipsListSnippets = "<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
" end of ultisnips

au BufNewFile *.jinja2 so ~/.vim/header/jinja_header.txt
au BufNewFile *.py so ~/.vim/header/py_header.txt
au BufNewFile *.sls so ~/.vim/header/sls_header.txt

let mapleader = ","
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
let g:ctrlp_map = '<leader>f'
let g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings = {
    \ 'AcceptSelection("e")': ['<c-v>', '<2-LeftMouse>'],
    \ 'AcceptSelection("v")': ['<cr>', '<RightMouse>'],
    \ }
" airline
set laststatus=2
" end of airline

" highlight excess line length (79)
autocmd Filetype py rst textwidth=79
set colorcolumn=+1

" go
let g:go_highlight_functions = 1
let g:go_highlight_methods = 1
let g:go_highlight_structs = 1
let g:go_highlight_operators = 1
let g:go_highlight_build_constraints = 1
" end of go

" neocomplete
" let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1
" end of neocomplete

" disable folding
set nofoldenable
" end of disable folding

" disable matchparen
" let loaded_matchparen=1
" end of disable matchparen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hightlights correctly for me.

:setf sls

and see what happens.

Judging by your .vim file your jinja files aren't being picked up by the ftdetect which triggers on *.sls

Comment: ah, you made me remember this: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/218. So, I've just updated salt-vim plugin, change `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jinja2 set filetype=sls.jinja2` to `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jinja2 set filetype=jinja`, everything is ok now.